# Help Designing an Electric Wheel Hoe: Identifying Required Materials and Torque Control Mechanisms

Tags: mechanical-engineering, robotics, servo

I am currently working on designing an electric wheel hoe, and I need help determining the required materials for its construction. The goal of this project is to create an automated version of a manual wheel hoe. Instead of relying on manual force, I want to use a motor to generate the necessary torque for the hoe tool to pass through the soil and remove weeds.

I need assistance in identifying the specific parts and components that the hoe tool would require. These parts should enable the hoe tool to consistently maintain a certain angle from the ground while applying a specific amount of torque. The angle of the hoe tool should be adjusted based on feedback received from the hardness of the soil as it moves through it. If the desired angle cannot be maintained with the ground, the torque should be increased. Alternatively, if sensory data indicates that the ground is too difficult to penetrate, the system should not apply torque.

[image: Figure 6: Mannual Wheel Hoe, Internet image]

[image: Figure 5: Atuomated Wheel Hoe, CAD Design by me!]

For a better understanding of the forces involved, please refer to the free body diagram below:

[image: Free body diagram forces applied to mannual wheel hole]

[Lastly, will this servomotor be able to move the mechanical arm](https://www.amazon.ca/ZOSKAY-Coreless-Digital-Stainless-arduino/dp/B07SBYZ4G5/ref=asc_df_B07SBYZ4G5/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=459447999510&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=18232059705603062590&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9000960&hvtargid=pla-864564315824&mcid=d173e367fff8367f9db3cc45ca5e5a43&th=1)

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on the specific parts required for the hoe tool, considering the torque adjustment mechanism based on soil hardness and angle maintenance. Thank you!

Comment: This question is very likely to be closed as "too broad". I suggest that you edit it down to one specific question that requires an engineering solution. You can, of course, ask other separate questions on other aspects of the design. Welcome to E.SE.

Comment: Where could you suggest an edit may be needed?

Comment: The photos are fine. Put a "background" heading on most of the text. Ask one clear question that can be answered at the end and make the title reference that.

Comment: the hoe breaks up soil ... it does not remove weeds ... the downward force in the handle is required to keep the tool below the soil level, that will have to be replaced by a large weight

Comment: Lead acid batteries make great weights. Alternative to a large weight may be an auger that is drilled in and pulled up, much like an earth anchor.  Makes tilling a lot less consistent, but keeping device weight low can have benefits.